# What difference '/' makes if it appears at the end of the URL

Tags: tomcat, url, trailing-slash

I want to understand what difference `/` makes in the URL, for example:

```
http://localhost:8080

http://localhost:8080/
```

Basically I have installed Apache Tomcat, and access these URLs.

Can anyone help me in understanding in simple words what difference a trailing slash makes in the URL?

Comment: None actually. If present it means that the URL refers to a directory, but Tomcat will try that anyway if the resource referred to by the URL doesn't exist as a file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So is this behaviour same for example on JBOSS AS?